# adding class or hooks inside app component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

i'm new to react world, in react sites it says that hooks cannot be used inside class, my question is for example i have app.js can i have components inside it which are class based and also functional (hooks) ? for example in this App.js can 'NavBar' be functional (hooks) component and 'Page' be class component or can those have inside them class/hooks components ?

```js
const store = configureStore({});


const Loader = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <div>loading...</div>
  </div>
);

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: yellow
    secondary: black
    action: {
      selected: orange[600],
    },
  },
  status: {
    danger: 'ooooo',
  },
});

const TranslatedApp = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    return (
        
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={hist}>
                <NavBar siteName={t('siteN')} />
                <Page />
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    
    );
};
const SuspendedApp = withTranslation()(TranslatedApp);
const App = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <SuspendedApp />
    </Suspense>
)

const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");
wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper) : null;
```

Comment: You can make `<NavBar>` a class component (but you cannot use Hooks inside of it) and `<Page>` a functional component and combine them in App.js

Comment: but can '<NavBar>' as a class component have another component inside which is hooks based ?

Comment: Yes. You will simply import it to `<NavBar>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There are no restrictions on what type of Component a child component has to be to the Parent. Your only restrictions are within the component when you declare it as functional or class. Class Components and Functional Components both have their own advantages, and both should be utilized according to what your Component will do (however, it should be noted after version 16.8.0, most of the features that a Class component had prior to that version can be done with Functional Hooks, however there are still situations where Class components may serve your purpose better, like when dealing with a dynamic DOM).

Comment: so if a  component is declared class, then can we have inside it another component which is using hooks ?

Comment: yes. There are no restrictions. Just with the type of Component.

Comment: then what does this means 'Your only restrictions are within the component when you declare it as functional or class'

Comment: Meaning WITHIN the component, not what you import into the component

Comment: so imported components(hooks) within class based component are allowed ? and vice versa

Comment: Yes. As default there are no restrictions enforced on children of Class Components or Hook Components

Comment: I guess you have misunderstanding with regard to what Hooks really mean. They do not define the type of the component (it can either be class or functional) but serve as a tool to manage state and other React features in functional components. Check this article - [Hooks at a Glance](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)